# PowerShell Script to enable Creation of Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I know Central Admin can be controlled using PowerShell mostly if not all. What I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way to enable/disable the creation of subsites in Central Admin using a PowerShell script.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://mywebapp
$allowSubsites = $false


$newPermissions=$null   
if ($allowSubsites){
    $newPermissions=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]($webApp.RightsMask -bor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::ManageSubWebs)
}
else
{
    $newPermissions=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]($webApp.RightsMask -band [System.Int64](-bnot ([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::EmptyMask -bor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::ManageSubWebs)))
}

$webApp.RightsMask = $newPermissions
$webApp.Update()
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986946/programmatically-access-user-permissions-for-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Does this work with SharePoint 2013? Im getting this error message:  Cannot convert value "18446744073701163007" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int64."

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "WEBAPPURL"
$newPermissions=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]($webApp.RightsMask - 
band [System.Int64](-bnot ([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::EmptyMask -bor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions]::ManageSubWebs)))
$webApp.RightsMask = $newPermissions
$webApp.Update()
```

Executing these lines will automatically remove the “Create Subsite” permission from your web application, thus prevent any users from ever creating subsite.

Refer below for more details:
http://nikcharlebois.com/prevent-subsite-creation-in-sharepoint-using-powershell/